# How to Publish Jacoco Report in Jenkins Using Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Statage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jacoco

Can you please any one tell me how can publish the Jacoco Report in Jenkins.

I mean after the pipeline execution done the test report need to show on the jenkins dhash Borad.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jacoco step available with Jacoco plugin

```
jacoco classPattern: "**/classes", sourcePattern: "**/src/main/java"
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jacoco/#-jacoco-record-jacoco-coverage-report

You can play around with this on the Snippet Generator available at `https://<yourJenkins>/pipeline-syntax/`

Comment: thanks. got the step from Snippet Generator. now it is showing in jenkins dash board .

Comment: thanks. got the step from Snippet Generator. now it is showing in jenkins dash board .

But am not able to see package coverage percentage and class coverage and line coverage  etc

Comment: you might have given the wrong class or source pattern? what I gave you is a general example. it worked for me on a spring boot project

Comment: great! don't hesitate to validate my answer then, it helps me gain reputation and helps other members of stackoverflow know if the question is already answered